# Less significant findings using conditional logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, bioinformatics, clogit

I used regular logistic regression on my dataset and got a few significant hits. However, since the data is 1:1 case-control matched data I decided to try using conditional logistic regression (`clogit()` in the `survival` package of `R`).

However, none of the results are significant any more. Is this normal? I was hoping to gain power by switching to conditional logistic regression.

```r
m <- clogit(PHENO==2 ~ x + as.factor(COVAR[, 1]) + strata(COVAR[,2]) )
```

This is a GWAS (genome wide association study). `PHENO` is either 1 (control) or 2 (case). `x` is number of copies of the minor allele (0, 1, or 2) in the SNP of interest, `COVAR[, 1]` is a race covariate and `COVAR[, 2]` is the matching covariate.

This test is performed for each SNP (~300,000) and the resulting p-values are adjusted for FDR.

Perhaps the matching of the cases and controls was not very good?

Matching: case and control pairs had:

1. same sex.
2. BMI > threshold.
3. same self-reported ethnicity.
4. lived within 50 miles of procurement site.

Perhaps I should use GLMM?

Comment: It might help if you posted your code for each, as well as a description of the matching variables. If your initial regression did not account fully for matching, then it may be biased upwards.

Comment: Other than the fact that I would code control = 0 and case = 1, the clogit looks fine, so the problem is likely with your initial regression. Can you post that? It's possible that using 1,2 for the outcome is causing some weird behavior, I suppose, but that seems less likely. I don't think the FDR adjustment would affect things. You could be right that the matching hasn't worked very well - are you only matching on one variable?

Comment: I'm just the poor biostatistican analyzing the data from this nation wide study. It is so hard to get any information out of these investigators...It takes like weeks for them to get back to me. I doubt the 1,2 coding causes problems since PHENO==2 turns it into TRUE/FALSE coding.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt the 1,2 coding is a problem. I would have expected more power with the clogit as well. With appropriately matched case-control data I would trust the conditional logistic results more than the regular logistic results. There could be a problem with insufficient control of confounding. Alternately, the matched variable may be inappropriate - is it definitely associated with both the outcome and exposure? If not, you can have decreased precision in the clogit and/or bias in the regular regression.

Comment: My adviser said it could also be that when I did the unconditional logistic regression it was too liberal of a test (assumptions of independence is violated because we have matched data) so that could explain the decrease in significance.

Comment: @Azula R. and @Benjamin, I tested with the example data from `clogit()` and found there is no difference whether outcome coded as 0-1 or 1-2. Is your code for unconditional logistic regression like `glm(PHENO==2 ~ x + as.factor(COVAR[,1]), family = binomial)`? It is possible that the results of `clogit` become insignificant, since unconditional logistic regression does not account for the correlation between matched subjects thus fails to make correct and efficient inferences on the mean model.

Comment: Note that the unconditional logistic regression would be unbiased, but has incorrect estimation of variability of the regression coefficient. See [here](http://ehs.sph.berkeley.edu/hubbard/longdata/webfiles/Chapter_3_Feb_2006.pdf).